# CREATE TABLE with column of certain value if other column has a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

Im trying to create table that has two certain columns. In one of them (deliverer) there are a few possible values. In second, there are few possible values as well. Value in second column is required only if deliverer has value 'A', otherwise it can be (and should be in fact a NULL)

this is my atempt

```
CREATE TABLE dict_shipping_types ( 
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    deliverer varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    gage varchar(1)
)
;
ALTER TABLE dict_shipping_types
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_dict_shipping_types_deliverer CHECK (deliverer IN ('CompanyA','CompanyB','CompanyC'))
    ;
ALTER TABLE dict_shipping_types
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_dict_shipping_types_gage_not_null 
        CHECK (
            (DELIVERER='CompanyA' AND GAGE IN ('A','B','C') AND GAGE != NULL ) OR 
            (DELIVERER!='CompanyA' AND GAGE=NULL)
        )
;
ALTER TABLE dict_shipping_types ADD CONSTRAINT PK_dict_shipping_types 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
;
```

Test Queries

```
INSERT INTO dict_shipping_types(deliverer) VALUES('CompanyA')

INSERT INTO dict_shipping_types(deliverer,GAGE) VALUES('CompanyB','A')

INSERT INTO dict_shipping_types(deliverer,GAGE) VALUES('CompanyA','D')
```

All of them should fail, but only third one does. How in check i can allow `NULL` or `NOT NULL` values?

Comment: So if deliverer is `A`, Gage should be `A`, otherwise, Gage should be `NULL`? Does that really have to be stored at all? Surely you can always deduce what value Gage *would* have had based on deliverer?

Comment: I've modified example to be more specific. Previous had a error. If deliverer is 'A' ,then gage can have value form rage (A,B,C), otherwise it has to be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it with `NOT NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` instead of `!=NULL`/`=NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE dict_shipping_types ( 
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    deliverer varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    gage varchar(1)
)
;

ALTER TABLE dict_shipping_types
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_dict_shipping_types_deliverer CHECK (deliverer IN ('CompanyA','CompanyB','CompanyC'))
    ;

ALTER TABLE dict_shipping_types
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_dict_shipping_types_gage_not_null 
        CHECK (
            (DELIVERER='CompanyA' AND GAGE IN ('A','B','C') AND GAGE is not NULL) or
(DELIVERER!='CompanyA' AND GAGE is NULL)
);

ALTER TABLE dict_shipping_types ADD CONSTRAINT PK_dict_shipping_types 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
;
```

Comment: This is correct and i'm embarrassed, that i did not checked for, even though I thought about it, but convinced myself that `NOT NULL` is equal to `!=`. Thanks